# mysql database replication using phpmyadmin on xampp

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, database-replication

My query is to setup database replication (master/slave) process to balance database load using phpmyadmin in xampp. I tried. There is one link in phpmyadmin called replication.

I followed this below link :
http://ahmedzubayr.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/configure-master-slave-replication-mysql-xampp/

While configuring MySQL Slave Configuration, I got an error like slave not configured on master. I cannot find these issue. Can anyone make a suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SVarun, just in case you missed [the point about your edit block](http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/653310): please stop putting everything in code blocks. Please use code for code only. Thanks.

Comment: First of all you need to create a user on the Master server that the Slave will connect as.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL must be accessible via network.
If you ran the command `/opt/lamp/lamp security` when you installed XAMPP, probably MySQL wasn’t accessible via network. You must comment the `skip-networking` line in `/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf` and restart XAMPP.